# How do I store an embed code to Mongodb through a form?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating a music blog website and I want to embed a video by submitting iframe embed through a form. So my question is how do How do I store an embed code to Mongodb through a form?

I have tried submitting the video into the form in UTF-8 ECMAScript but it still did not work

```
var artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    title: String,
    image: String,
    content: String,
    description: String
});
```

```
// CREATE ROUTE - add new artist to DB
app.post("/songs", function(req, res){
    // get data from form and add to Artist array
    var name = req.body.name;
    var title = req.body.title;
    var image = req.body.image;
    var content = req.body.content;
    var desc = req.body.description;
    var newSong = {name: name, title: title, content: content, image: image, description:desc}
    // Create a new artist and save to DB
    Artist.create(newSong, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //redirect back to songs page
            res.redirect("/songs");
        }
    });

});
```

I can get everything to display except the content which should have been the embed video code

Comment: are you using ejs? Which template engine are you using? If it's ejs you need to <%- varName %>

Answer (score 0):

This is your model:

```
const artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    title: String,
    image: String,
    content: String,
    description: String
});
```

This is your route. I rewrote it.

```
// CREATE ROUTE - add new artist to DB
app.post("/songs", async (req, res) => {
    // get data from form and add to Artist array
    const { name, title, image, content, desc  } = req.body
    const newSong = { name, title, content, image, description:desc }
    try {
      // Create a new artist and save to DB
      await Artist.create(newSong)
      res.redirect('/songs');
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error)
    }
});
```

In your form you should rename desc to description for clean destructuring. It would be helpful to know how you're sending the data.

```
<form action="/songs" method="POST">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="title">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="content">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="image">
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea name="desc"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```